# how to put a class in classes2.dex when use multidex in android studio

Tags: android, android-multidex

I would like to put a class into the second dex when use multidex.

I have tried several methods but failed. I use d`exKnife` and the methods show in google android-development documents.

How can I keep the classes in the  primary dex? I want to put some classes in the second dex.

Comment: is your application required multiple dex file .. ? if yes thn why you need to create dex files as per your own requirement ?

Comment: to protect the class ..so  i put it in the second dex and encrypt it . so  first i  have to put it in the second class

Comment: have tried to define to keep classes in  buildTypes of build.gradle file ?
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#keep